Auto refresh a power query in macro spreadsheet that pulls data from web pages
I have a macro embedded spreadsheet that uses a macro to refresh multiple power queries to import data tables from web pages. I need the data to refresh daily at a set time.
I tried using task scheduler on a remote desktop (as it can remain on 24/7) to trigger a batch file to run a VBA script which, among other things, triggers the macro to refresh the data. However it fails at the refreshing the power queries part.
If I trigger the batch file manually on the remote desktop using command prompt, it works fine. But the second I try to run it in task scheduler it locks up and wont complete the task. I believe it has something to do with it trying to access the web pages, as all other tasks I have in the scheduler, that don't import data from web pages, run fine.
This is the macro I'm running:
Sub Workbook_Refresh()
    
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Exchange Rates Query").Refresh
    
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Japan Natural Gas (USD)").Refresh
    
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Henry Hub Natural Gas").Refresh
    
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries("EU Natural Gas (EUR)").Refresh
    
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries("UK Natural Gas (GBP)").Refresh
       
    End Sub

and all the power queries are similar the the following:
let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=GBP&amount=1"),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", "TABLE.ratesTable:nth-child(4) > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}, {"Column2", "TABLE.ratesTable:nth-child(4) > * > TR > :nth-child(2)"}, {"Column3", "TABLE.ratesTable:nth-child(4) > * > TR > :nth-child(3)"}}, [RowSelector="TABLE.ratesTable:nth-child(4) > * > TR"]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Extracted Table From Html", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"British Pound", type text}, {"1.00 GBP", type number}, {"inv. 1.00 GBP", type number}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"British Pound", "Currency"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"

If anyone has any ideas how to get this running, either using task scheduler or another method, I'd be very grateful.

Is your Task Scheduler task running as a specific user?
